# Lifecycle policy on S3 not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have simply enabled a file cycle policy on a bucket in Amazon S3. This is the configuration:

```
root@iserver:~# aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket ee-shares --profile s3toglacier
{
"Rules": [
{
"Status": "Enabled",
"Prefix": "",
"Transitions": [
{
"Days": 180,
"StorageClass": "GLACIER"
}
],
"ID": "test"
}
]
}
```

But I cannot see data on Glacier and objects older then 180 days do not show "Initial Restore" option in S3.

Comment: *"I cannot see data on Glacier."*  You won't see anything in Glacier in the AWS console.  S3 doesn't use *your* Glacier account.  It uses its own interconnection with Glacier.  Also, editing the metadata on any given object will reset the 180 day counter for that object, so be aware of that.

Comment: Did you configure this through the Management Console, or via a `put-bucket-lifecycle` call? If it was via a call, perhaps try the configuration via the browser? Your policy exactly matches one that I have in place, which works successfully, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Amazon S3 lifecycle policies do not execute immediately. Allow up to 24 hours for them to archive content.

Once archived, the objects will still appear in Amazon S3, but their **storage class** will be set to `Glacier`.

Comment: It takes more then 3 days.

Comment: I have a Lifecycle set to delete objects after 24 hours. But, objects are not deleted after 24 hours. More like after 2 days? How can I delete objects after 24 hours?

Comment: @blade19899 -- If the lifecycle policy isn't working as desired, you can always write your own code to do it on a schedule. Please ask another Question if you require assistance with this.

Comment: @blade19899 did you figure out how do it?

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K I don't remember fixing this. I just left this as is. I think :/

Comment: It's a shame if this is the case but I am also experiencing objects not deleting 13 hours after the expiration date. Objects that I can view the details of have my lifecycle rule listed as applicable to it and the storage class is still showing as `Standard`.

Comment: I can confirm that the items that were marked for deletion have gone. It took about 24 hours for my files.

Comment: From the Amazon docs: "Amazon S3 rounds the transition or expiration date of an object to midnight UTC the next day. For example, if you created an object on 1/1/2020 10:30 UTC, and you set the lifecycle rule to transition the object after 3 days, then the transition date of the object is 1/5/2020 00:00 UTC. Before you check whether a lifecycle rule has been satisfied, be sure to verify that enough time has elapsed".

Comment: More details in AWS blog: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-lifecycle-rule-delay/

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily add expiry (for e.g expire current versions of objects) of objects in the same lifecycle rule and set days after object creation to a large number (for e.g *2147483647*). This will allow you to test if your lifecycle policy is attached to your objects or not.

```
export BUCKET_NAME=YOUR_BUCKET_NAME
export KEY_NAME=KEY_NAME

aws s3 api head-object --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key KEY_NAME

Output:
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "Expiration": "expiry-date=\"Fri, 30 Sep 2022 00:00:00 GMT\", rule-id=\"transistion-glacier-expire\"",
    "LastModified": "2022-07-01T08:53:49+00:00",
    "ContentLength": 13932,
    "ETag": "\"90ef2da5ad155a608342f88b51f36111\"",
    "ContentType": "text/html",
    "Metadata": {}
}
```

Now we can see **Expiration** header and it will provide details of lifecycle rule associated with it.

**Note:** Remember to remove above test expiry rule from your lifecycle policy after testing your changes.